# Action Bar of Tabs at the top and Bottom, should work together

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

I want Action Bar at the Top as well as at the bottom, both should works together.
that the effect that comes to topped tab, should also be on the bottomed tab. 
I have designed this one, works perfectly, but I need two Tabs. 
Need Help.
The Pink Image with Action Bar at the Top and Bottom is my Requirement.

[image]

The Pink Image with Action Bar at the Top and Bottom is my Requirement.

[image]

Comment: May ask why? In my opinion, and probably Google's as well, that's a bad UI design.

Comment: its requirement of my client.

Comment: That's unfortunate... you could maybe try a `PagerTitleStrip` at the bottom or suggest to your client that that's a bad idea?